# 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, phpmyadmin

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/phpfile/leave-option.php' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
<?php
// Handle preflight OPTIONS request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    // Allow only specific origins instead of '*'
    $allowed_origins = array('http://localhost:8100');
    $origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : '';
    if (in_array($origin, $allowed_origins)) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $origin);
    }
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");
    exit; // Stop further execution
}


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pis";
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Execute query to fetch options
$query = "SELECT id, TypeofLeave AS name FROM leave_info"; // fixed sql query
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

// Fetch data from the result set
$options = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $options[] = $row;
}

// Return options as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($options);
?>
```

fetching data and display it on ionic-select options`

Comment: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS')` - and if not ...? You are not outputting those headers for the second request being made with the _actual_ requested method, but _only_ for the pre-flight OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORs on your server: https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors#a-enabling-cors-in-a-server-you-control